# Microsoft jscript runtime error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jscript

I'm getting a Microsoft jscript runtime error popup with the usual "object doesn't support this property or method" message.

The problem is, I have no idea why this message pops up or what program it belongs to, and I have no idea how I can dig up more information from the popup itself.

It pops up seemingly random. Always a while after startup and about 2-3 more times whether I'm using my computer or not. I get no more feedback when I click "OK" or X it away.

Anyone know how I can figure out what program the popup belongs to?

Edit: It repeats itself a couple of times when either clicking OK or X. Right after clicking, it pops up again, but stops after the 3 times.

Comment: Did you mean Microshoft?

Comment: Damn h always gets in there...

Comment: There supposed to be a line number and filename too in that error message. Can't you trace the error source with them?

Comment: No line number or filename...

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone know how I can figure out what program the popup belongs to?

1) Install [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

2) As soon as an error dialog box appears do not close it. Use "Find windows's process" tool (see [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dthwc.png)) by selecting the popup window (dialog box with the error message).

3) Process Explorer will show you the process that generates an error.

If you need to debug the root cause do the following:

4) Install Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop (free of charge)

5) Start IDE and choose Debug/Attach to Process.

6) Use 'Select...' button to change the type of code. Choose 'Script'.

7) Attach to your faulty process and have fun ;)